# Failure to update Homebrew

Tags: osx, homebrew

So I'm trying to update my home brew version but I get an error. Here is a copy pasted part from the console:

```
$ brew update
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
Library/Formula/v8.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
$
```

Now, reading this makes it seem like I have change the `v8` formula file, but I have not. Going to the file at `/usr/local/Library/Formula/v8.rb` and looking at it shows that it was last edited in 13 November, 2014. But I could update yesterday.

And I'm not sure how to "stash" my changes. Any idea what do to? Force overwrite it possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what the error was but this fixed it:

```
cd `brew --prefix`
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Then I could `brew update` just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
git --git-dir $(brew --repository)/.git reset origin/master --hard
git --git-dir $(brew --repository)/.git clean -fd
```

See: [Common Issues with Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Common-Issues.md)

For further Git issues, check:

- [How do I resolve git saying “Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15745045/55075)